# Spark streaming from hive table, is it possible?

Tags: hive, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have  a use case

1. We have java framework to parse realtime data from Kinesis to Hive table in every half an hour.
2. I need to access this hive table and do some processing near realtime. An hour delay is fine, as I dont have permission to access Kinesis stream.
3. Once processing is done in spark (pyspark preferably), I have to create a new kinesys stream and push the data.
4. I will then use Splunk and pull it near realtime.

Question is, any one has done spark streaming from hive using python ? I have to do a POC and then the actual work.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I did spark streaming with automatic generated log files.

Comment: you can use spark directly as if you don not have to save data at local .. process stream ans send stream from spark..

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to go ahead on this:

1. Use spark-streaming to obtain messages drectly from Kinesis. That will give you something that is real time.
2. Once the file drops into your staging area ( either your hive ware-house OR your some HDFS location ), you can pick it up for processing using spark-streaming for files.

Do let us know which approch worked best for you.